# Why do so many crystal radios have big coils?

Tags: inductor, radio, coil, crystal-set

I've been looking at crystal radios recently, and I noticed that many of them had quite big coils (maybe around 5cm on average from what I can see), but wouldn't they want quite a low value inductor to get the right frequency without using an absolutely miniscule capacitor? I know the size would have been quite useful for tapping, but wouldn't they have still wanted them as small as possible?

These are some of the images I found, they are all modern recreations and kits, but ones made to look like the old ones:

[image: Crystal radio with big coil 1]

https://steampunk.wonderhowto.com/how-to/complete-guide-build-crystal-radio-plus-they-work-0141117/

[image: Crystal radio with big coil 2]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_radio

[image: Crystal radio with big coil 3]

hackaday.com/2020/01/28/eric-talks-crystal-radios/

[image: Crystal radio with big coil 4]

https://www.mtcradio.com/the-pickard-crystal-set-radio-kit/

This is the equation I was using to calculate the frequency:

[image: LC oscillator frequency equation]

https://www.elprocus.com/lc-oscillator-circuit-working-and-its-applications/

These were the formulas I was using as a reference for inductors (I know they're air-core, but they showed me that increasing the radius of the coil increases the inductance, which should be the same for a ferrite-core inductor as well)

[image: Air core inductor formulas]

https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/uploads/articles/round-wire-formula.jpg

Comment: The capacitors are tiny (value wise.)  Those humongous variable capacitors had values in the picofarad range. That goes together with the relatively low inductance of the large air cored coils.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note how these inductors are **air filled** so even though they're physically large in size, that doesn't mean they also have a large inductance.

Indeed tapping off a signal is much easier with large inductors and that is I think the actual reason why they're this large.

With a smaller inductor tapping will be more difficult, the wires are not isolated, if they were, tapping off would be impossible (unless you remove the isolation first). Also the un-isolated wires cannot touch as that would short the inductor.

Also, with a smaller inductor you would get a **smaller voltage** (at a higher current but that doesn't help) so the output signal would be smaller resulting in a lower volume in the (high impedance, crystal) headphones.